# FileInput different behavior in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, file, google-chrome, firefox, input

I've experienced a weird issue, on using HTML FileInput, Firefox doesn't truncate the filename beside the Browse button if it's too big, but Chrome does that.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
<input type="file" name="attributeDefaultValueFileInput" id="attributeDefaultValueFileInput" />
```

Firefox:
[image]

Chrome:
[image]

Since I've implemented this functionality to be usable in a fixed size popup, I'm facing the issue that if this filename becomes too big, my popup becomes scrollable, I don't want that.

Is there a way to force firefox to behave like Chrome in this case?

Comment: You could always create your own UI, but actually, that looks like a bug in FF: Mine does truncate too long file names just like chrome, but it does it very wrongly : https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2qJj.png Hmm it's been discussed here https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1365434 You could add your insight.

Comment: Ah and actually I may have misread your question, but you can simply add a `max-width` on your input.

Answer (score 0):

A quick workaround will be to wrap the input with a `div` and set `overflow:hidden` on div's css.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/2088/

HTML:

```
 <div>
  <input type="file" name="attributeDefaultValueFileInput" id="attributeDefaultValueFileInput" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

In case of firefox, the fullname of file is visible when user hovers on the input.

Comment: This works to truncate, but Chrome truncates it to give a better view of filename and file extension. Can we achieve that?

Comment: @dushyantashu That's a browser behavior which you cannot control. But you can come close to it.